# Meaning of "drag" in "lights stretching across the main drag spelled..."

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *drag* in this context? (From first paragraph of “[The Sanctuary](http://www.newyorker.com/reporting/2011/12/19/111219fa_fact_batuman)”, by Elif Batuman, **New Yorker**, December 19, 2011)

> Directly outside the window, Vegas-style lights stretching across the main drag spelled, in two-foot-high letters, “WELCOME TO THE CITY OF PROPHETS.”

Comment: This is a general reference question: http://onelook.com/?w=main+drag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drag

> 6: street, road <the main *drag*>

Comment: To describe the main street as the main drag is a common slang expression. "The primary commercial street in a smaller city."  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drag